# TensorFlow checkpoints and models vis-a-vis multi-gpu settings

Tags: tensorflow

Let us take a practical situation a researcher often finds him/herself into when using TensorFlow :

- Multiple GPUs are available for training and I'd like to use them for speedup.
- Subsequently I'd like to give the trained model to a colleague or collaborator with a different (maybe 1 !!) number of GPUs.
- It is important that the code need not be modified for use when shared with multiple collaborators.

However, TensorFlow documentation/examples are not very clear/explained for such a scenario.
Basic questions are :

1. How do I write a code which involves training a model with multiple GPUs and where the model can be easily restored from checkpoints ?
2. How do I deal with the situation where my collaborators have different number of GPU resources ? More precisely, what best practices should I follow to ensure that the code and model I share with them is easily usable by them ?

Are there some examples or best practices other TensorFlow users (facing the same situation !!) can share ?

**NOTE** : I am not looking for a readymade solution. My prime purpose is to understand a TensorFlow feature which is not very well documented.